# Is there a way to set the QT icon theme, and other theme elements, from the command line?

Tags: command-line, kde, qt

I'm trying to automate the process of theming QT5 programs, in the absence of a DE like KDE, by writing a script that does it. I know that GTK has a bunch of config files that can specify all the aspects of a theme, but what's the equivalent for QT5?

So far, I've found out that I can set `QT_THEME_OVERRIDE` to set the theme, and `XCURSOR_THEME` to set the cursor theme (QT5 appears to respect this). But what about the icon theme and everything else?

I've also seen [this Arch Wiki section](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/qt#Configuration_of_Qt5_apps_under_environments_other_than_KDE_Plasma) about a similar issue, and a few other questions that suggest using the graphical configurator `qt5ct`, but I'm really trying to write something that makes this change, rather than have a configurator do it, so that I don't have to repeat this process if I replicate my system install somewhere else.

(This is so I can write a .nix expression for home-manager that can handle qt5 theming declaratively, but that's beside the point.)

Answer (score 0):

If you still care about this, check out  [my config](https://github.com/balsoft/nixos-config/blob/9f7ad468dbe6cbdb1ce65f2efcf6d62980355f96/themes/default.nix#L115).
I am using nix & home-manager as well, so this might be useful. (Though this doesn't quite work for nixos-unstable right now because pure-qt apps don't use correct icon theme. I don't know what to do). You should do something like `xdg.configFile."kdeglobals".text = kde;` where kde is defined above.